# Storyboard returns nil need some quick advise how to instantiate

Tags: xcode, ipad, storyboard, instantiation

I run into the following problem. In my iPad app using storyboard.

```
-(UIViewController *)SetDetailVideoView
{
    // assign/instantiate self. storyboard, but how?
    VideosViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VideoViewController"]; //empty but why? Because self.storyboard is empty
    NSLog(@"%@",self.storyboard); //NULL
    return vc;
}
```

`Self.storyboard` returns **nil** so everything it try to get return nil and gives an exemption?
So how do i instantiate `self.storboard`.

Comment: Check your identifier in storyboard class may be you have set different identifier in iPad

Comment: Checked it and is was set and correct

Comment: Can you show your code of instantiating `self.storyboard`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use below code to instantiate your storyboard

```
self.storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: Just found the answer  myself. but here you go, i checked your answer as right.

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: The line of code was the solution it needed a specification of storyboard with name. I found the same solution as you suggested. Sorry i didn't make that clear, english isn't that easy.

Comment: Can anyone help with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38959445/astoryboard-instantiateviewcontrollerwithidentifiermyid-returns-nil-but-not?noredirect=1#comment65274351_38959445

Answer (score 2):

I don't like the hard coded style. You can also use:

```
[self.navigationController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VideoViewController"];
```

Comment: This one worked for me when self.storyboard didn't. Not entirely sure what the logic is, it's probably linked to how the view controller is instantiated. It's worth noting self.navigationController will be nil if a view controller was modally presented, so this wouldn't work in those instances.